# Java - Package preventing java from finding/loading main method

Tags: java, command-prompt, notepad

I have this program with 3 source files, being pretty new to java I recently learned that I should package these. So I went and did that, I already knew a little about packaging. However, after trying to run the class file with the main method, java could not find/load the main method.

After a while, I finally discovered that the cause was the package line. When the package line is there, the error appears, when the package line isn't there (or is commented out), the program runs fine.

```
package PeriodicTable;

class PeriodicTable {
public static void main (String[] args) {
  //Lines of code
}
}
```

According to various tutorials and the java doc, all you need to do is put the package line, the package name and a semi-colon at the end. Google searching the error (with package as the cause) did not help me.

I've tried changing the package name, so it was not the same as the class name, this did not work.

What am I using?

Notepad

Command Prompt

Java 8

As for my question... Why is the package line preventing java from finding/loading the main method? How do I fix this?

Comment: To run it:  > java PeriodicTable.main params.

Comment: How are you attempting to run the program? You must add the package to the invocation. You should add an example of how you are invoking the program.

Comment: @kevino He says it's using command prompt and notepad.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you said, but I tried (java PeriodicTable.main) (java PeriodicTable.main() ) (java PeriodicTable.main(); ) None of these worked.

Comment: @kevino Originally I just did: java PeriodicTable (in command prompt), I have already confirmed that the location of where the file is will work (by running other programs in this location)

Comment: You have to create a folder named `PeriodicTable` (this is the same as the package line) and put your `PeriodicTable` class inside.  This can help to you:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Comment: My directory for the files is: C:\projects\PeriodicTable  The PeriodicTable folder holds all my class files, source files and other things that my program needs. I have my paths setup so I can use the Java 8 commands (like javac or java) in any directory.

Comment: @JoseLuis, my question was to assist the OP in understanding that whereas before it would have been something like `java -cp SOME_PATH PeriodicTable` (the command line invocation), it will now be `java -cp SOME_PATH PeriodicTable.PeriodicTable`. One must add the package name to the invocation. The *exact command* used to call the program is what I was after. And, for the record, `PeriodicTable.main` is just wrong.

Comment: @kevinoYou are right, I'm sorry, the '.main' has to be removed.  I just wanted to point that the package was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the package directory, in your case it is PeriodicTable. Run following commands

```
$ javac -cp . PeriodicTable/PeriodicTable.java 
$ java -cp .  PeriodicTable.PeriodicTable
Hello
```

Following [link](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2014/03/importing-packages.html) may help you.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I will have to test it with a few things to make sure it will work with my overall intention. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've noticed this as well in the past. I just remove the package, since I'm usually calling just a couple programs from the same package anyway at most. :) My mantra is, if it works, take yes for an answer and move on...l

Comment: Though this is a big task for me, I am creating a full program of the Periodic Table of the Elements for my High School (as an extra project). So I am going to have around 5 classes or so. I could just find out how to import the required classes, but in the near future I will be taking just as big or bigger projects... It would be good for me to learn how to make packages that will run without issues. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad you posted this actually, as it's been something has nagged me, but I haven't had the need to figure it out, as I usually do web based development and very small utility projects.